# Joining two dataframe and keep all column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do join-like sql statement in python using pandas.

I have these two dataframe

df1:

```
id  name
7   MPS
10  MCM
11  MIB
12  NEW-MCM-DEV
15  SAMS
16  NEW-MCM-VIT
```

df2:

```
main_id numberOfNodes tier_id   tier_name               
7       2             29        MPS-Online           
7       0             247       Offline-b24-settle  
7       0             246       Offline-bank-data-feed  
7       1             256       Offline-Citynet-Recon   
7       1             433       WAS 
10      8             26        APP 
10      2             296       BATCH   
10      2             358       BBO
```

I want to join these 2 dataframes based on id (df1) and main_id(df2).

My desired output is

```
main_id numberOfNodes tier_id   tier_name               name
7       2             29        MPS-Online              MPS
7       0             247       Offline-b24-settle      MPS
7       0             246       Offline-bank-data-feed  MPS 
7       1             256       Offline-Citynet-Recon   MPS
7       1             433       WAS                     MPS
10      8             26        APP                     MCM
10      2             296       BATCH                   MCM
10      2             358       BBO                     MCM
```

I tried using

```
df2.merge(df1, left_on='main_id', right_on='id')
```

and tried using

```
df2.join(df1, on=['main_id'], how='outer')
```

but none work because the name field on df1 is not showing on the output. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: what was the output of df2.merge(df1, left_on='main_id', right_on='id') it should work i think

Comment: silly me, i forgot to save the result to a variable. it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas function `concat`.

> Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic along the other axes.

There is some ways to use that, first of all using in the way asked on the question:

```
pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

In this case pandas will fill the missing values with NaN. Example:

[image]

If you prefer ignore rows with missing values, you can use:

```
pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='inner')
```

In this case the join between the dataframes will work as a Inner join on SQL. Example:

[image]

And if you want to keep some dataframe structure just completing this structure with the new columns, you can use:

```
pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
```

In this case the resulting dataframe will have the same rows of `df1` but with some extras columns of `df4`. Example:

[image]

More information can be founded on [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: Thanks man, my code actually works but your solution also works plus it fills the missing value!